# Optimize query / subquery for better performance (slow)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have query with a subquery that takes about 15 seconds to complete. Even if I don't join the 2 tables, it's pretty slow, so it's not the joins that is eating up time. the jos_payplans_subscription table has 8200 rows and a size of 3.3 MB.

Some user have both an active and expired membership. I want to find all users how is not active (status = 1603) and doesn't have an other active membership.

The query works - just slow.

Question: Can I do better?

Thanks

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.username, c.email, a.plan_id, d.title, a.subscription_date, a.expiration_date
FROM jos_payplans_subscription a
    LEFT JOIN jos_users c ON c.id = a.user_id
    LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_plan d ON d.plan_id = a.plan_id
WHERE a.status = 1603 
AND a.user_id NOT IN (SELECT b.user_id FROM jos_payplans_subscription b WHERE b.status = 1601)
```

And here's the create table for the 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_payplans_subscription` (
  `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `subscription_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `expiration_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `cancel_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `checked_out` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out_time` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `params` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subscription_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15103 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `jos_payplans_plan` (
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `ordering` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out_time` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `description` text,
  `details` text,
  `params` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`plan_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `jos_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(400) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `block` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sendEmail` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `registerDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `lastvisitDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `activation` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `params` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastResetTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date of last password reset',
  `resetCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Count of password resets since lastResetTime',
  `otpKey` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Two factor authentication encrypted keys',
  `otep` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'One time emergency passwords',
  `requireReset` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Require user to reset password on next login',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_block` (`block`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `username` (`username`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_name` (`name`(100)) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23158 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: did you add indexes on fields used by the search ? also are you on local  or on a webserver to make the test ?

Comment: When asking questions about query optimization, you should run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table in your query, and include the definition in your question. Otherwise, we have to guess at your data types and indexes. Also run `EXPLAIN <query>` for the SQL query you are asking about.

Comment: @BillKarwin I've added show create table for the 3 tables. I see the primary table; jos_payplans_subscription has no index.

Comment: @zeflex I'm testing on a live high performance websever who is only running this one website

Comment: @zeflex I manually added a new index to the table and this really did wonders. Went from 15 seconds to 0.5 seconds - amazing :-) Thanks for the pointer - didn't think of that, as the table was created as part of an extensions for Joomla CMS

Comment: @Dyvel cool. I added the answer in big, you can vote for it and close the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to add indexes on search fields, if you don't have them in your tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query should work for you. It makes use of LEFT JOIN, instead of NOT IN, and in general that will perform significantly faster.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.username, c.email, a.plan_id, d.title, a.subscription_date, a.expiration_date
FROM jos_payplans_subscription a
LEFT JOIN jos_users c 
ON c.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_plan d 
ON d.plan_id = a.plan_id
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_subscription b 
ON b.status = 1601
AND b.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE a.status = 1603
AND b.plan_id IS NULL
```

This assumes that `jos_payplans_subscription.plan_id` cannot be NULL. If it can, pick any other column that is NOT NULL to use for the `b.plan_id IS NULL` part of the query.

If the query is still too slow then we'll need to take a look at your indexes and column datatypes, so add `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for all tables involved to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're looking for all users that only have a 1603 membership, we could try a WITH clause using an [EXCEPT](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-except-clause.htm).

Edit: Okay, no EXCEPT in MySql so that query isn't much help.

```
WITH 
 users_1601 as (
  SELECT user_id FROM jos_payplans_subscription WHERE status = 1601
 ),
 subs_1603_only as (
  SELECT a.user_id, a.plan_id, a.subscription_date, a.expiration_date
  FROM jos_payplans_subscription a 
  LEFT JOIN users_1601 b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
  WHERE a.status = 1603
  AND b.user_id is NULL
 )
SELECT 
   c.id, c.name, c.username, c.email, 
   subs.plan_id, subs.subscription_date, subs.expiration_date,
   d.title
FROM subs_1603_only subs
LEFT JOIN jos_users c ON c.id = subs.user_id
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_plan d ON d.plan_id = subs.plan_id
```

In reality, I just shuffled things around a bit. Assuming other practices, such as proper indexing, are done, I think the goal for this query is to make sure that the subquery (user_ids for status 1601) is not executed for every row in the main query. Sometimes pulling that out into a WITH clause helps.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an EXCEPT operator.

Comment: Yeah, you're right on that. Google fail there on my part.

Comment: Hah, now that I edited my query, I see that its using the same trick as Willem's query.

Answer (score 0):

- Change `NOT IN ( SELECT id ... )` to `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * ... AND b.user_id = a.user_id )`.  Reason:  There is not need to collect 'all' the ids, there is only a need to see if any exist.
- Switch to InnoDB; there are many optimizations that are available only in InnoDB.
- Collect the ids that you desire before `JOINing` to `c` and `d`.  That is, `SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT ... ) LEFT JOIN c ... LEFT JOIN d ...`